# Julia: Search string vector for a character and add that character

Tags: string, julia

I want to detect if a character exists in my vector of strings and if it does not add it to the end.

```
mystrings = ["asfs", "asfsaf", "sfas.sdg", "dsgsd", "sdgsd."]

for i=1:length(mystrings)
  if !contains(mystrings[i],".") mystrings[i] = mystrings[i] * "." end
end
```

The above works. I am writing this more to ask, if I should have instead used some kind of broadcasting or if this was the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code you posted. A broadcasting solution might look like

```
mystrings .= (x->contains(x, '.') ? x : x*".").(mystrings)
```

or if you prefer a map style

```
map!(x->contains(x, '.') ? x : x*".", mystrings, mystrings)
```

Both (and your solution as well) avoid allocation by modifying the array.

Comment: I ended up doing the following: `mystrings[!contains.(mystrings,".")] = mystrings[!contains.(mystrings,".")] .* "."`. I realized part of my problem with finding the broadcasting solution was that I had not upgraded my workstation to v6.0.

Comment: Yes, v0.6 is much nicer for that. This solution (which would be idiomatic in R) is not quite as good, in fact. I think you may be allocating a temporary array in `!contains.(mystrings, ".")` which you do twice, as the approach with using them for indexing may mean that the automatic dot fusion cannot abstract them away ( https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots ) (I am not sure of this, though). Also, by using `=` rather than `.=` you allocate a new temporary array on the RHS, which you don't need to.

Comment: Also, `!contains.(mystrings, ".")` should be `.!(contains.(mystrings, "."))` on 0.6. I just ran benchmarks, and your original solution and both of mine benchmark around 130 ns and are equivalent. Your final solution benchmarks at 6 microseconds and is thus 40 times slower.

Comment: I ended up going with, `map!(x->contains(x, ".") ? x : x*".", mystrings)`. Though I see you edited it to, `map!(x->contains(x, ".") ? x : x*".", mystrings, mystrings)`?

Comment: Yeah, looks like the `map!` syntax for overwriting the input changed. Aren't you getting deprecation warnings?

Comment: Nope, running `v0.6.0`. IDK

Comment: Weird. Anyway, I believe that is the new syntax.

Comment: Maybe, the warnings have not been updated on the windows build.

Comment: It is better to use Char type for the dot, that is `contains(x, '.')` and `x*'.'`. Chars might potentially produce better optimized code (haven't benchmarked it)

Comment: I've updated the response for the convenience of future readers. Note though that `x*'.'` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't but `x*'.'` works fine on version 0.7.0-DEV.1257

Comment: Huh, it doesn't on 0.6.0. But it's nice that it does now.